# How can I call text_field_tag with an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, helper

Consider this:

```
text_field_tag :phone, :class => "input span2", :id=>"follow_up_phone"
```

However, if we now have the arguments in an array: `[:phone, {class: "input span2", id: "follow_up_phone"}]`

How would I call text_field_tag using that array?

```
text_field_tag array
```

doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: where's your value? The signature is:

```
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

So, you have to call it this way:

```
text_field_tag :phone, nil, :class => "input span2", :id=>"follow_up_phone"
                        ^
```

And your `array` has to be:

```
[:phone, nil, {class: "input span2", id: "follow_up_phone"}]
```

Use splat operator to pass this array:

```
text_field_tag *array
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `:phone[]` will work. For example, I've done this before in a form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="question_id[]" value=<%= q.id %>>
```

where the parameter is an array of question ids.

Hope that works!